# How can I get my answer associated with my account for a migrated question?

Tags: support, user-accounts, merge-accounts

How can I get answer of my Associated my account know that I have created a WebApp SE account. Here is the [question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/9984/is-aerial-view-officially-gone-from-maps-in-microsofts-bing) I referring to too.

Answer (score 4):

See also this question: [Can I claim my migrated answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71358/can-i-claim-my-migrated-answer)

In a similar situation, I was instructed to flag the post with a message asking it to be linked to my new account.